# Java can't find symbol but I have no typos

Tags: java

I have the error: "Java: can't find symbol" every time one of my public methods in my java file is called from a java test file but as far as I can tell none of the usual mistakes that make this error come up are in my code. Here is some of the Java file being accessed:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class SneakyQueens
{
  private static final int UO = 0;
  // Given an ArrayList of coordinate strings reprsenting the locations of the queens
  // on a boardSize x boardSize chess board, return true if none of the queens can
  // attack one another. Otherwise, return false.
  public static boolean alltheQueensAreSafe(ArrayList<String> coordinateStrings, int boardSize)
  {
    // maximum number of queens that can still be safe is equal to boardSize because
    // none may share a column or row
    if (coordinateStrings.size() > boardSize)
      return false;

    int[] colCo = new int[boardSize + 1];
    int[] rowCo = new int[boardSize + 1];

    // parsing each element of the ArrayList and evaluating column and diagonal
    // values as they are stored
    for (String co : coordinateStrings)
    {
      int colVal = parseCoordinateString(co, 1);
      int rowVal = parseCoordinateString(co, 0);

      // if column is unoccupied, place flag in column coordinates array
      if (colCo[colVal] == UO)
      {
        colCo[colVal] = 1;
      }
      else
      {
        return false;
      }
```

and here is some of the test file trying to access SneakyQueens.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TestCase02
{
    private static void checkTest(boolean success)
    {
        System.out.println(success ? "Hooray!" : "fail whale :(");
    }

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.clear();
        list.add("a1");
        list.add("b2");
        checkTest(SneakyQueens.allTheQueensAreSafe(list, 60000) == false);

        list.clear();       
        list.add("a2");
        list.add("b1");
        checkTest(SneakyQueens.allTheQueensAreSafe(list, 60000) == false);

        list.clear();
        list.add("xx342");
        list.add("xy343");
        checkTest(SneakyQueens.allTheQueensAreSafe(list, 60000) == false);
```

Comment: `alltheQueensAreSafe` != `allTheQueensAreSafe`, java is case sensitive.

Comment: Where is `parseCoordinateString`?

Answer (score 0):

- You seem to not be using packages, which might be an explanation why you can´t access SneakyQueen from "the outside".
- If you do not declare or do not want to declare an instance of SneakyQueen, you should make it abstract.